# Why does Yoo Eunsong forget S.O.U.L in her future vision?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-management

In the final episode (episode 16 ending) of [*Top Management*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Management_(TV_series)) (Korean drama), after Yoo Eunsong changes the future in the last episode, why does she not remember S.O.U.L?

Answer (score 1):

In the last few episodes of Kdrama "Top Management", Yoo Eunsung realizes that she and her Grandmother are not the only ones who can see the future, but there are others also (like Park Hyuk Gwon, the councilor candidate) who have similar powers.

After talking to Hyuk Gwon, she comes to realize two things. (1) Just like frustration leads to bad dreams, unhappiness can lead to undesirable events in future. Likewise happiness is key to a favorable outcome. (2) She should not lose her present while foreseeing other people's future.

When president Seo Kang announces her departure from Starlight and is about to leave, Eunsung unexpectedly sees one possible future (All futures are only possibilities as they can change just like dreams!). It shows her that if she stays in Starlight, Eunsung shall become a Team lead who is under pressure and also S.O.U.L group might disintegrate in future.

She figures out that, if she wants to avoid this, then she should change something in the present. By leaving with Seo Kang, she will be happy and might also be able to change the future. As a result, she decides to leave Starlight and join President Kang into her new venture.

Since Eunsung changed a minor detail, she is able to change the future. As a result, When she foresees again (again another possibility in future), she sees that she (Eunsung) has become a Director (unlike team lead in her previous foresight). She is confident and happy and is able to keep her artists and team safe. Also, just like how she met Sooyong, she would meet another artist (Dongyoon). However, she pays the price of not being able to remember S.O.U.L and her association with them. (This might be the one precious thing she has to lose or the price that is paid for changing the future).

However, In the end we see that on Next Day, S.O.U.L members are actually deciding on whether they want to stay in StarLight (without Eunsung and Manager Kang) or not. And surprisingly (^-^) they all vote in favour of moving out of the company (all hands down, LOL ). This hints that the future has changed again (possibly due to Eunsung) and S.O.U.L might join Manager Kang and Yoo Eunsung and there is a new and  promising future. :-)